# Populate excel user form combo-box from html combo-box with vba

Tags: html, vba, excel, combobox, web-scraping

I have a user form that I would like the html option values to populate the excel combo box. Basically I want to duplicate the values and pass them later.

What I have is smashed together from various posts but nothing seems to work.

```vb
Dim appIE As InternetExplorerMedium
Dim nam As Object
Dim sel As Object

Set appIE = New InternetExplorerMedium
sURL = "site infor goes here"
With appIE
    .navigate sURL
    .Visible = True
End With
Do While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop
For Each f In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("select")
    If f = "suppliercode" Then
        For Each fOption In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("option")
            With Me.SupplierSite.AddItem(f.Option)
            End With
        Next fOption
    End If
Next f

ALSO TRIED:
Set Doc = IE.document.forms("NewReleaseQueueForm1")
For Each sel In Doc.getElementsByTagName("select")(0).Value
If sel.Name = "suppliercode" Then
'loop through and add each option to Me.SupplierSite
For Each opt In IE.document.forms("NewReleaseQueueForm1").getElementsByTagName("option")(0).Value
Me.SupplierSite.AddItem sel.Value
Next opt
End If
Next sel
```

HTML Sample:

```htm
<form id="NewReleaseQueueForm1" method="post" name="NewReleaseQueueForm1">
    <table cellpadding="4">
        <tr>
            <th valign="top">Supplier Site</th>
            <td valign="top">
                <select multiple name="suppliercode" size="5">
                    <option selected value="Any">
                        &lt;Any&gt;
                    </option>
                    <option value="T488C">
                        T488C
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
```

Comment: If f.name = "suppliercode" Then ???  Try that and step through to debug

Comment: It seems it doesn't like .additem and it skips over the if statement. Expected function or variable on .additem. I updated this thread with what I have tried

Comment: Try changing the line to "If f.NAME = "suppliercode" Then"  Some of your other code in that for loop won't work either.  The following link will take you through the process of getting the options from a select element.  It uses the GetElementById method, which you can replace with GetElementsByName("suppliercode")(0) method.  The zero is necessary because there may be more than one element named "suppliercode".  0 represents the first instance, 1 represents the 2nd instance, etc etc http://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/tag/get-option-values-from-drop-down-list-with-vba/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work. Thank you for your time and effort for those that posted.

```
Set IE = IE.document.frames(1).document
Dim supls As Object
Dim suplsDrop As Object
 Set suplsDrop = IE.getElementsByTagName("OPTION")
 For Each supls In IE.getElementsByTagName("SELECT")
  If supls.Name = "suppliercode" Then
 For Each suplsDrop In supls
  With Me.SupplierSite
  .AddItem suplsDrop.Value
  End With
Next suplsDrop
End If
Next supls
```

Answer (score 0):

Please place the following HTML code into notepad and save as an HTML file.  Open that file in MSIE

Then open a new clean workbook and paste the macro code below into in a standard module.  Make sure that your webpage is open in MSIE.  Go to the editor and put your cursor some where inside the "StartHere()" subroutine.  Press PF5 to run it.  A userform will open with the names of all open browser pages that are open.  Select the one with the title "Test Get Select Options".  A msgbox will appear to say that the page has been successfully put into an Excel Object.  Then check your worksheet to see if it listed the four options in column A.

If it works then clear sheet1 and open your web page.  Try the macro again and see if 9it works with your page.

**HTML:Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> <html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"> 
<title>Test Get Select Options</title> 
</head> 
<body> 

<form id="NewReleaseQueueForm1" method="post" name="NewReleaseQueueForm1">
    <table cellpadding="4">
        <tr>
            <th valign="top">Supplier Site</th>
            <td valign="top">
                <select multiple name="suppliercode" size="5">
                    <option selected value="Any">
                        &lt;Any&gt;
                    </option>
                    <option value="T488C">
                        T488C
                    </option>
                    <option value="R488C">
                        R488C
                    </option>
                    <option value="C488C">
                        C488C
                    </option>
                    <option value="Z488C">
                        Z488C
                    </option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

**Macro Code:**

```
Global myDoc As HTMLDocument
Global IE As Object
Sub StartHere()
    On Error Resume Next
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}", 0, 0    'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", 0, 0    'Microsoft Extensability for VBA
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{0D452EE1-E08F-101A-852E-02608C4D0BB4}", 0, 0    'Microsoft Forms
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{3050F1C5-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}", 0, 0    'Microsoft MSHTML
        ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid "{EAB22AC0-30C1-11CF-A7EB-0000C05BAE0B}", 0, 0    'Microsoft Internet Controls
    On Error GoTo 0
Call nextSub
End Sub
Sub nextSub()
        Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
        Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
        Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.codemodule
        Dim LineNum As Long
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.codemodule
        LineNum = 1
        CodeMod.insertlines 1, "Global myDoc As HTMLDocument"
        CodeMod.insertlines 2, "Global IE As Object"
        Call getOpenBrowserCreateForm
End Sub
Sub removeCode()
        Set VBProj = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
        Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents("Module1")
        Set CodeMod = VBComp.codemodule
        LineNum = 1
    For i = 34 To 4 Step -1
            CodeMod.DeleteLines i
    Next i
End Sub
Public myDoc As HTMLDocument
Public IE As Object


Sub getOpenBrowserCreateForm()
Dim myForm As Object
Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
Dim NewButton As MSForms.CommandButton, newButton2 As MSForms.CommandButton
'Dim NewComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim NewListBox As MSForms.ListBox
'Dim NewTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
'Dim NewLabel As MSForms.Label
'Dim NewOptionButton As MSForms.OptionButton
'Dim NewCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim x As Integer
Dim Line As Integer

'This is to stop screen flashing while creating form
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

On Error Resume Next
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\system32\scrrun.dll"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\system32\FM20.DLL"
On Error GoTo 0
Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

'Create the User Form
With myForm
    .Properties("Caption") = "Select Open Web Site"
    .Properties("Width") = 326
    .Properties("Height") = 280
End With

'Create ListBox
Set NewListBox = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.listbox.1")
With NewListBox
    .Name = "ListBox1"
    .Top = 12
    .Left = 12
    .Width = 297
    .Height = 207.8
    .Font.Size = 9
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleOpaque
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
End With

'Create CommandButton1 Create
Set NewButton = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton
    .Name = "CommandButton1"
    .Caption = "Select"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 228
    .Left = 234
    .Width = 72
    .Height = 24
    .Font.Size = 9
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With

'Create CommandButton2 Create
Set NewButton = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton
    .Name = "CommandButton2"
    .Caption = "Cancel"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 228
    .Left = 144
    .Width = 72
    .Height = 24
    .Font.Size = 9
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With

'add code for form module
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 1, "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 2, "Dim urlLocation As String"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 3, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 4, "''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 5, "''  This part gets all open web pages qand displays them on the form for user to choose"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 6, "''"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 7, "    Set objIterator = CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Shell.Application" & Chr(34) & ")"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 8, "    For X = 0 To objIterator.Windows.Count"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 9, "        On Error Resume Next"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 10, "        current_title = objIterator.Windows(X).Document.Title"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 11, "        current_url = objIterator.Windows(X).Document.Location"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 12, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 13, "        If current_title = ListBox1.Value Then 'is this my webpage?"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 14, "        "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 15, "            Set IE = objIterator.Windows(X)"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 16, "            MsgBox " & Chr(34) & "IE was properly set" & Chr(34) & ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 17, "            "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 18, "             Boolean_indicator = True"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 19, "            Exit For"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 20, "        End If"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 21, "    Next"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 22, "    Set objIterator = Nothing"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 23, "    Set myDoc = IE.Document"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 24, "Return"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 25, "Unload Me"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 26, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 27, "End Sub"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 28, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 29, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 30, "Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 31, " Unload Me"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 32, "End Sub"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 33, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 34, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 35, "Private Sub UserForm_Activate()"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 36, "    Dim myArray1() As String, tempNumb As Integer"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 37, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 38, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 39, "    i = 2"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 40, "    tempNumb = 1"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 41, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 42, "    ReDim myArray1(1 To 1)"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 43, "   "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 44, "    Set objShell = CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Shell.Application" & Chr(34) & ")"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 45, "    Set objAllWindows = objShell.Windows"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 46, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 47, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 48, "    For Each ow In objAllWindows"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 49, "        If (InStr(1, ow," & Chr(34) & "Internet Explorer" & Chr(34) & ", vbTextCompare)) Then"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 50, "            myArray1(tempNumb) = ow.Document.Title"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 51, "            tempNumb = tempNumb + 1"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 52, "            If Not ow.Document.Title = " & Chr(34) & "" & Chr(34) & " Then"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 53, "                ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To tempNumb)"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 54, "            Else"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 55, "                Exit For"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 56, "            End If"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 57, "        End If"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 58, "    Next"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 59, "     "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 60, "    Me.ListBox1.List = myArray1"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 61, "End Sub"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 62, ""
'Show the form
VBA.UserForms.Add(myForm.Name).Show

'Delete the form (Optional)
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove myForm

'   IE is now set to the user's choice and you can add code here to interact with it
'   myDoc is now set to IE.Document also
'
'
'

Dim drp As HTMLFormElement

Set drp = myDoc.getelementsbyname("suppliercode")(0)



Dim walekuj As Long
walekuj = myDoc.forms.Length
 MsgBox walekuj

'we get the option values into our worksheet

For x = 0 To 3
 Cells(x + 1, 1) = drp.Item(x).innerText
 Next x

'Now we select the option value of our choice

drp.selectedIndex = 2

' we free memory

Set IE = Nothing
 Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

Comment: user defined type not defined on `Global myDoc As HTMLDocument` and sub never exits. Always goes to expected end sub on line before end sub..

Comment: My bad.  Erase the two global variables first.  After the guid references are added it will replace them.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the referecnes in a clean workbook yourself through the VB editor "Tools" - "References."  They are '***Microsoft Scripting Runtime***,  '***Microsoft Forms***, '***Microsoft MSHTML***, and '***Microsoft Internet Controls***.  Then add the following code into the module and run getOpenBrowserCreateForm().  It's been working for me for years

```
Global myDoc As HTMLDocument
Global IE As Object


Sub getOpenBrowserCreateForm()
Dim myForm As Object
Dim NewFrame As MSForms.Frame
Dim NewButton As MSForms.CommandButton, newButton2 As MSForms.CommandButton
'Dim NewComboBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Dim NewListBox As MSForms.ListBox
'Dim NewTextBox As MSForms.TextBox
'Dim NewLabel As MSForms.Label
'Dim NewOptionButton As MSForms.OptionButton
'Dim NewCheckBox As MSForms.CheckBox
Dim x As Integer
Dim Line As Integer

'This is to stop screen flashing while creating form
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False

On Error Resume Next
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\mshtml.tlb"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\System32\ieframe.dll"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\system32\scrrun.dll"
Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "C:\Windows\system32\FM20.DLL"
On Error GoTo 0
Set myForm = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)

'Create the User Form
With myForm
    .Properties("Caption") = "Select Open Web Site"
    .Properties("Width") = 326
    .Properties("Height") = 280
End With

'Create ListBox
Set NewListBox = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.listbox.1")
With NewListBox
    .Name = "ListBox1"
    .Top = 12
    .Left = 12
    .Width = 297
    .Height = 207.8
    .Font.Size = 9
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BorderStyle = fmBorderStyleOpaque
    .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectSunken
End With

'Create CommandButton1 Create
Set NewButton = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton
    .Name = "CommandButton1"
    .Caption = "Select"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 228
    .Left = 234
    .Width = 72
    .Height = 24
    .Font.Size = 9
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With

'Create CommandButton2 Create
Set NewButton = myForm.designer.Controls.Add("Forms.commandbutton.1")
With NewButton
    .Name = "CommandButton2"
    .Caption = "Cancel"
    .Accelerator = "M"
    .Top = 228
    .Left = 144
    .Width = 72
    .Height = 24
    .Font.Size = 9
    .Font.Name = "Tahoma"
    .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
End With

'add code for form module
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 1, "Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 2, "Dim urlLocation As String"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 3, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 4, "''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 5, "''  This part gets all open web pages qand displays them on the form for user to choose"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 6, "''"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 7, "    Set objIterator = CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Shell.Application" & Chr(34) & ")"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 8, "    For X = 0 To objIterator.Windows.Count"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 9, "        On Error Resume Next"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 10, "        current_title = objIterator.Windows(X).Document.Title"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 11, "        current_url = objIterator.Windows(X).Document.Location"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 12, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 13, "        If current_title = ListBox1.Value Then 'is this my webpage?"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 14, "        "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 15, "            Set IE = objIterator.Windows(X)"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 16, "            MsgBox " & Chr(34) & "IE was properly set" & Chr(34) & ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 17, "            "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 18, "             Boolean_indicator = True"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 19, "            Exit For"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 20, "        End If"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 21, "    Next"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 22, "    Set objIterator = Nothing"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 23, "    Set myDoc = IE.Document"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 24, "Return"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 25, "Unload Me"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 26, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 27, "End Sub"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 28, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 29, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 30, "Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 31, " Unload Me"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 32, "End Sub"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 33, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 34, ""
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 35, "Private Sub UserForm_Activate()"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 36, "    Dim myArray1() As String, tempNumb As Integer"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 37, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 38, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 39, "    i = 2"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 40, "    tempNumb = 1"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 41, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 42, "    ReDim myArray1(1 To 1)"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 43, "   "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 44, "    Set objShell = CreateObject(" & Chr(34) & "Shell.Application" & Chr(34) & ")"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 45, "    Set objAllWindows = objShell.Windows"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 46, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 47, "    "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 48, "    For Each ow In objAllWindows"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 49, "        If (InStr(1, ow," & Chr(34) & "Internet Explorer" & Chr(34) & ", vbTextCompare)) Then"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 50, "            myArray1(tempNumb) = ow.Document.Title"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 51, "            tempNumb = tempNumb + 1"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 52, "            If Not ow.Document.Title = " & Chr(34) & "" & Chr(34) & " Then"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 53, "                ReDim Preserve myArray1(1 To tempNumb)"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 54, "            Else"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 55, "                Exit For"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 56, "            End If"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 57, "        End If"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 58, "    Next"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 59, "     "
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 60, "    Me.ListBox1.List = myArray1"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 61, "End Sub"
myForm.codemodule.insertlines 62, ""
'Show the form
VBA.UserForms.Add(myForm.Name).Show

'Delete the form (Optional)
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True

ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove myForm

'   IE is now set to the user's choice and you can add code here to interact with it
'   myDoc is now set to IE.Document also
'
'
'

Dim drp As HTMLFormElement

Set drp = myDoc.getelementsbyname("suppliercode")(0)



Dim walekuj As Long
walekuj = myDoc.forms.Length
 MsgBox walekuj

'we get the option values into our worksheet

For x = 0 To 3
 Cells(x + 1, 1) = drp.Item(x).innerText
 Next x

'Now we select the option value of our choice

drp.selectedIndex = 2

' we free memory

Set IE = Nothing
 Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```